# Question about CONCAT and DATE and Have Clause SQL

Tags: sql

I am practicing writing SQL queries, I'm working with a baseball database. The table I'm concerned with is named people with attributes nameFist, nameLast, debute_date, and final_game.

I'm attempting to find the first name and last name (as one field) and debut date of people whose final game was 10,000 days after their debut. Order by the date difference.

So far I have:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nameFirst,'',nameLast) as name, debut_date FROM 
PEOPLE;
```

How would I find the people whose final game was 10,000 days after their debut? debute_date and final_game are formatted like so: Year-Month-Day e.i. 2014-02-28.

I can't just simply add 10,000 days to final_game.

Comment: What you need is highly specific to your DBMS which should be tagged along with `sql`

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the DATEDIFF function. So the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nameFirst,' ',nameLast) as name, debut_date
FROM PEOPLE
WHERE DATEDIFF(final_game, debut_date) > 10000
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(final_game, debut_date);
```

The DATEDIFF function may vary depending on if you are using MySQL or SQL SERVER.

For SQL SERVER, the query might look like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nameFirst,' ',nameLast) as name, debut_date
FROM PEOPLE
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, debut_date, final_game) > 10000
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(d, debut_date, final_game);
```

Comment: I've tried this in the data base! It was successful. It allowed me to use the first one you referenced. So it takes the debut_date and subtracts the final_game from it, then sees if the days passes are greater than 10000. Should I say ">=" instead of ">"?

Comment: There is a problem with how `concat()` handles NULLs.

Comment: @Styles That depends on the query that you are trying to write. If you want the difference to be strictly greater than 10000, then use `>` otherwise go with `>=`.